Ref all sections that refs current section
I am creating a group of Security Playbooks with associated Actions that needs to be performed by various teams.
The playbooks and actions have a many to many relationship, and while it is easy to label each actioncard with a label and referencing them when needed in the playbooks, I would also like to highlight any plabooks that reference the action card, on the action card.
So is there a package or a way to reference all sections/chapters that refs the current section/chapter, or just a specific label?

Welcome to TeX.SE!

Maybe this answer to 'Usage of table/figures shown in caption' helps

Rdfref can do this. Unfortunately, it is not yet on CTAN, because I've never forced myself to write the documentation. But you can see what is possible posts linked from the README
